# Cannot use rsync: I get "connection refused" even when port 22 is open

Tags: networking, server, ssh, rsync, ufw

I'm trying to use rsync command in order to copy a big backup file from the server to my laptop.

I'm logging in with ssh into my server, and then try to do the download of the file:

```
rsync -vae ssh backup-24-03-2018.sql rosamunda@190.192.75.254:/home/rosamunda/Desktop/
```

This is the error that I've got:

> ssh: connect to host 190.192.75.254 port 22: Connection refused rsync:
>
> connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
>
> rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]

So I did check the firewall:

```
sudo ufw status
```

> Status: active
>
> To                         Action      From
>
> --                         ------      ----
>
> 22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
>
> 22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

So, why I keep having the error? what am I doing wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Ps. I've read [the docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) about ufw and it seems that I've done everything as I should...

Comment: So you are trying to rsync **from** the server **to** the laptop? Can you confirm that the UFW status is that of the laptop? and an SSH server is running on the laptop and listening on port 22?

Comment: Yes, I did exit the server and then run `sudo ufw status`